# R: compilation failed for package ‘CompQuadForm’, a dependency for seqMeta

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install seqMeta package in R, but having troubles because it won't compile the "CompQuadForm" dependency package.

Can you suggest a solution?

Here is the output:

```
> install.packages("seqMeta")
also installing the dependency ‘CompQuadForm’

trying URL 'http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/CRAN/src/contrib/CompQuadForm_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 15316 bytes (14 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 14 KB

trying URL 'http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/CRAN/src/contrib/seqMeta_1.6.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1162086 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘CompQuadForm’ ...
** package ‘CompQuadForm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/work/gyorgy/PROGR/R/R-3.2.5/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c imhof.cpp -o imhof.o
imhof.cpp: In function ‘double theta(double*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*)’:
imhof.cpp:18: error: ‘atan’ is not a member of ‘std’
imhof.cpp: In function ‘double rho(double*, double*, int*, double*, double*)’:
imhof.cpp:29: error: ‘exp’ is not a member of ‘std’
imhof.cpp: In function ‘double imhoffunc(double*, double*, int*, double*, double*, double*)’:
imhof.cpp:40: error: ‘sin’ is not a member of ‘std’
make: *** [imhof.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘CompQuadForm’
* removing ‘/work/gyorgy/PROGR/R/R-3.2.5/library/CompQuadForm’
ERROR: dependency ‘CompQuadForm’ is not available for package ‘seqMeta’
* removing ‘/work/gyorgy/PROGR/R/R-3.2.5/library/seqMeta’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpHn3Spw/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("seqMeta") :
  installation of package ‘CompQuadForm’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("seqMeta") :
  installation of package ‘seqMeta’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thank you,
Beata

Comment: Not a proper solution, rather a quick workaround if you are using ubuntu: a pre-compiled version of CompQuadForm is available in [this PPA](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u/+build/11097404) (you can download directly the .deb file there)

Comment: @GyB Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue with CompQuadForm using R 3.2.3. However, I would note that I was able to install it on R 3.3.1. Still, I'd like a solution if you (or anyone) has found one.

Comment: The link provided by @Jealie not working anymore, here is another one that contains deb package of CompQuadForm, for Ubuntu:
http://mirror.cs.uchicago.edu/cran2deb4u/pool/main/c/compquadform/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the R version, install old versions.

Comment: Could you expand on your response? I think the install.packages function only searches for packages matching your R version and warns you otherwise. Do you suggest installing an older version of the package? if so, could you provide example code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).